# Export FAST Search Scopes Using Powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010, fastsearch

I want retrieve the fast search scopes created in one environment and restore them in a new environment.Has anybody tried this?

Answer (score 0):

I have this to get you started...

First you have to export the scopes, and then the scope rules:

```
# Search Service Application Name
$searchAppName = 'Search Service Application'

# Get Search Service Application
$searchApp = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication $searchAppName

# Get the Scopes
$scopes = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchQueryScope -SearchApplication $searchApp

# Export scopes to CSV
$scopes | Export-Csv -Path Scopes.csv

# Get the Scope Rules
$scopeRules = $scopes | Get-SPEnterpriseSearchQueryScopeRule

# Export scope rules to XML
$scopeRules | Export-Clixml -Path ScopeRules.xml
```

Now to import the scopes:

```
# Search Service Application Name
$searchAppName = 'Search Service Application'

# Get Search Service Application
$searchApp = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication $searchAppName

# Get .CSV file with Search Scope information
$File = 'Scopes.csv'

# Loop through the CSV file entries
$csvData = Import-Csv $File | ForEach-Object {
    Write-Host Creating Search Scope... $_.Name
    # Create New Search Scope
    $new = New-SPEnterpriseSearchQueryScope -SearchApplication $searchApp -Name $_.Name -Description $_.Description -DisplayInAdminUI ([System.Convert]::ToBoolean($_.DisplayInAdminUI))
}
```

For the search scopes, I am not sure if this will work, you may have to import them one scope at a time, and specify the scope that the rules apply to.

```
# Get .XML file with Search Scope Rule information
$File = 'ScopeRules.xml'

#Import XML
$scopeRules = Import-Clixml $File

# Create New Search Scope Rule??
$scopeRules | New-SPEnterpriseSearchQueryScopeRule
```

Then you can start scope update compilation

```
# Start Scope Update Compilation to add the new rules
Write-Host Start Scope Update Compilation...
$searchApp.StartScopesCompilation()
```